# Нейросети на сколько это сложно?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Всем привет.
Есть пару вопросов, так как часто слышу, о том что кто-то пытается создать свою нейросеть, либо стремится к этому. У меня вопрос, насколько это сложно сделать? На каких языках ее нужно делать? Есть ли примеры для "детей"?

Допустим очень простая нейросеть, построенная на каком-либо языке, чтобы понять как она работает, "поиграться" и начать добавлять что-то свое, улучшать ее? То есть нужны какие-то базовые азы, от А до Я, для старта. Цель? Просто хочу попробовать как это работает и насколько это сложно. Нужно ли знать высшую математику или базовую, тот или иной язык. Также, если кто-то сталкивался -поделитесь опытом. Спасибо.

Comment: Есть готовые библиотеки, выполняющие функции нейронной сети. Нужно лишь обучить их. Думаю, что лучше всего нейронные сети запускать на тех языках, где ожидается небольшое быстродействие.

Comment: Нейросети - довольно обширная и сложная  для "человека с улицы" тема. Ограничений по языку нет, но в индустрии  машинного обучения популярны Python, R и Scala. На "попробовать" можете взять пакет TensorFlow для Python. Из математики нужны по крайней мере линейная алгебра и теорвер со статистикой.

Comment: Поиграться с уже обученной сетью можно тут: http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.76595&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false

Comment: Если хотите занятсья всерьез - обратите внимание на курсы по Machine Learning и Deep Learning от Udacity.

Comment: Как вариант, вот отличная [JS-библиотека](http://caza.la/synaptic/).

Comment: Просто хотелось бы иметь какой нибудь туториал, от А до Я что бы очень простым языком был расписан каждый пункт, т.е описание действий кода и т д. И конечно как можно проще. Что бы понять базовую основу самой нейросети на простом примере. Желательно на C# если есть. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Нейросети - это не выбор языка, а математика. Ее можно реализовать на любом языке. Минимум необходимых знаний - матрицы (сложение и умножение). 
Вот отличный курс пример курса от Стенфорда - там используется Octave - построите нейросеть с нуля - https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning. Насколько знаю, нейросети написаны почти на всех языках, да еще не по одному разу. Как правило, сначала оценку делают на Python или в математических языках типа Octave/Mathlab - кому как удобнее. Если модель окажется рабочей - то ее уже иногда переписывают на C++/Java для лучшей интеграции с основным софтом организации. Сам прошел этот курс - очень рекомендую (посмотрите кто преподаватель)